# What is wrong with this trigger? After Insert Update

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have problem with simple trigger on MySQL.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER cust_tracer
AFTER INSERT ON custom_values 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE 'custom_values' set 

  (VALUE = CONCAT('https://tracker.123e33.eu/view.php?id=', VALUE))
  where custom_field_id=84;

  END$$
```

the VALUE is a column in table custom_values thats named VALUE

I got the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''custom_values' set
>     VALUE = CONCAT('https://tracker.123e33.eu/view.php?id=' at line

Comment: Remove the parenthesis around the assignment.

Comment: You should state what *exact* problem you have.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''custom_values' set 
  
  VALUE = CONCAT('https://tracker.123e33.eu/view.php?id=' at line

Comment: Not in the comments. [Edit] your question and add the information there.

Comment: And remove the single quotes around the table name.

Comment: You cannot action the table which caused the trigger to fire , in the trigger. This looks like it should be a before insert trigger where you could amend NEW. values

Comment: And the trigger seems strange to me. Every time you insert a new row into the table you want a column of one row prefixed with that URL fragment? So after a while that value will have that prefix a lot of times. Is that really what you want achieve?

Comment: Yes the value is simple: 133214 the result will be tracker.123e33.eu/view.php?id=133214  that will be an url link :)

Comment: And after the next insert it will be tracker.123e33.eu/view.php?id=tracker.123e33.eu/view.php?id=133214

Comment: AFTER INSERT ON ?? there is now insert or update

Answer (score 0):

Removing the parantheses around the SET statement will solve the issue.

The query block will be:

```
BEGIN
   UPDATE `custom_values` SET
   VALUE = CONCAT('https://tracker.123e33.eu/view.php?id=', VALUE)
   WHERE custom_field_id = 84;
END$$
```

Comment: still:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''custom_values' set   
  VALUE = CONCAT('https://tracker.123e33.eu/view.php? at line 5

Comment: @ArturStolc Have you tried as `UPDATE \`custom_values\` SET ` or `UPDATE custom_values SET `

Comment: Yes i have now 
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER cust_tracer
AFTER INSERT ON custom_values 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE easy.custom_values set   
  VALUE = CONCAT('https://tracker.123e33.eu/view.php?id=', VALUE)
  where easy.custom_field_id=84;
  END$$

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8